# How to Disable Horizontal Scroll bar in ComboBox in SWT

Tags: java, combobox, swt, jface

I have created a combo Box but I am experiencing a strange behavior, If number of Elements in my Combobox is <= 2, I am unable to see a Horizontal scroll bar.
[image]

But if they are more than 2 then I see a horizontal scroll bar automatically pop up. 
What I would like is, to disable the horizontal scroll bar. This is the code I am using.

```
preferredResourceCombo = Components.createCombo(controlComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
        gridData.widthHint = 150;
        preferredResourceCombo.setLayoutData(gridData);

        preferredResourceCombo.addVerifyListener(new ComboAutoSelectVerifyListener());

        // preferred resource combo modify listener at bottom of method
        preferredResourceComboViewer = new ComboViewer(preferredResourceCombo);
        preferredResourceComboViewer.setLabelProvider(SelectionItemLabelProvider.getInstance());
        preferredResourceComboViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
```

I am using the same code everywhere but only here I am getting this behavior.What could be the possible causes?

[image]

Comment: I think some platforms give you either no scroll bars or both scroll bars - you can't have just one. This is a feature of the native control so it can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug report about this [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=209157).

Unfortunately, there is no solution so far.